# Docker container does not sync volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have created a container with docker-compose, it runs without a problem, the database is connected right but the volumes are not in sync between the container and local folder. I started it with the following code:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    image: "prestashop/prestashop:1.7"
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      - PS_DEV_MODE=1
      - XDEBUG_CONFIG
      - PS_INSTALL_AUTO=1
      - PS_FOLDER_INSTALL=installDirHasToBeRenamed
      - PS_FOLDER_ADMIN=admin1234
      - ADMIN_MAIL=admin@shop.com
      - ADMIN_PASSWD=admin1234
      - DB_SERVER=database
      - DB_NAME=prestashop
      - DB_USER=root
      - DB_PASSWD=admin
      - PS_INSTALL_DB=1
      - PS_ERASE_DB=1
    networks:
      - network
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html/modules/mymoduledir
      # Do not forget to remove directory when removing containers with `docker-compose rm`
      - .docker/web:/var/www/html

  database:
    # MySQL 5.7 is recommended for the Docker version
    # https://hub.docker.com/r/prestashop/prestashop/
    image: "mysql:5.7"
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
    networks:
      - network

networks:
  network:
```

This is a prestashop 1.7 module, the given directory is the one where it will be installed, so I tried the following things to make this work:

1. I used chmod on the container's side so it can be used but it did not worked, prestashop still wasn't able to use that folder
2. from a fresh start I deleted the folder, this way it was possible to install the module but the local changes wasn't showed up in the container.

Comment: Having 2 bind mounts that share a path in the container might be why you're seeing this, i.e. `/var/www/html` and `/var/www/html/modules/mymoduledir`.

Answer (score -1):

please replace `.` by `$(pwd)` not that for your database you don't have volumes mounted.

```
    volumes:
      - $(pwd):/var/www/html/modules/mymoduledir
```

best practice would be in any case :

```
rootfolder
|-Docker-compose.yaml
|-web/
  |-directory_to_mount
|-postgres/
  |-directory_to_mount
```